# BitmapImage SetSource Crashing/Freezing App

Tags: windows-runtime, taglib, bitmapimage, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to set the image from a stream. However when I set the source from the background thread and use a dispatcher it freezes the app completely. The stream is not null, I have verified that.

I am using the taglib api to get the stream of the album picture of an mp3 file. I've tried everything.

```
async void Background(object sender, MediaPlayerDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{         
   IRandomAccessStream AlbumArtStream = await Media.GetAlbumArt(MediaFile.Name, await MediaFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync());

   await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
   {
        ViewModel.NewAlbumArt = new BitmapImage();
        NewAlbumArt.SetSource(AlbumArtStream);
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to set it async? `await NewAlbumArt.SetSourceAsync(AlbumArtStream);` And where do you invoke this method?

Comment: Thanks, with Async it appears to work. Although I thought in the Dispatcher SetSource was the correct use, I guess I was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like in comment - to prevent freezing your app, call `SetSoruceAsync`:

```
async void Background(object sender, MediaPlayerDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{         
   IRandomAccessStream AlbumArtStream = await Media.GetAlbumArt(MediaFile.Name, await MediaFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync());

   await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
   {
      ViewModel.NewAlbumArt = new BitmapImage();
      await NewAlbumArt.SetSourceAsync(AlbumArtStream);
   }
}
```

You may read more [at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapsource.setsourceasync.aspx):

> Setting an image source by calling the asynchronous SetSourceAsync method rather than the similar SetSource method avoids blocking the UI thread. ...