# Creating BitmapImage in Converter Blocks Execution

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1, ivalueconverter

I am binding an an Image Source to a byte array and using a converter to create the image from the byte array.

This is my Xaml

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="OfferImageTemplate">
        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,6">
            <Image Source="{Binding ImageByteArray, Converter={StaticResource BinaryImageConverter}}"/>
        </Grid>
 </DataTemplate>
```

And this is the converter

```
public class BinaryImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value != null && value is byte[])
        {
            byte[] bytes = value as byte[];
            BitmapImage btmimage = new BitmapImage();
            using (MemoryStream memstream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
            {
                using (var a = memstream.AsRandomAccessStream())
                {
                    a.Seek(0);
                    btmimage.SetSource(a);
                }                   
            }
            return btmimage;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }        
}
```

The problem is that when `btmimage.SetSource(a)` is executed the UI blocks completely and nothing happens after that.
There is no exception thrown.

Do you have any idea as to why this happens?

The contents of the byte array are correct as they have been tested elsewhere.

This is a Windows 8.1 store application.

Comment: does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/23926022/891715

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The problem is that I can't call async functions in the converter. I would have used SetSourceAsync otherwise.

Comment: it seems there is a way to use SetSourceAsync in a converter - check out this thread: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windowsapps/en-us/1f75d1ea-66dd-44ca-a06d-5070643967f2/xaml-image-from-path

Comment: It seems like that could work. I also found an implementation of an asynchronous value converter. However I solved my problem using [this](https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2013/04/15/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-image-in-a-windows-store-app/) solution